# Generators of Special Linear Matrix ???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a simple question, anyone can help:

Can one generate this matrix $A_1$ or $A_2$ or $A_3$ from two matrices $B$, $C$ and their inverse ($B^{-1}$, $C^{-1}$):

$$
A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0& -1& 0\\ 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix},\;\;\;
A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 0& -1\\ 0& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix},\;\;\;
A_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 1\\ 0& 1& 0\\ -1& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

From:
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 1\\ 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix},
\text{ 
and   }\;\; 
C=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& 0\\ 0& 1& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

> i.e. question: can one **EXPLICITLY** write down an expression, such that:
>   $A_1= B \cdot C \cdot B^{-1}\cdot C^{-2} \cdot B^{-1} \dots$, 
>   or
>   $A_2= C \cdot B \cdot C \cdot B^{-4}\cdot C^{-3} \cdot B^{-2} \dots$, for example?

the answer requires an explicit form, please, thank you!